# How can I display both of JSX elements in the same row without one or another?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

How can I display both of the conditions next to each other in the same line?

If using the first one just show the images if using the second one just show the video.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";

function LastArticles({ postagem }) {
  const [isImage, setImage] = useState(true);
    const [isImage, setImage] = useState(true)
  const Condition1 = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Card className="my-3 p-3" rounded>
          <a href={`/postagem/${postagem._id}`}>
            <Card.Img
              className="containerImg"
              src={postagem.media}
              variant="top"
            />
          </a>
                    <Card.Img className="containerImg" src={postagem.media} variant='top' />
          <Card.Body>
            <a href={`/postagem/${postagem._id}`}>
              <Card.Title as="div">
                <strong>{postagem.title}</strong>
              </Card.Title>
            </a>
                </a>
            <Card.Text as="h4">Criado :</Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </>
    );
  };
                <Card.Body>
  const Condition2 = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Card className="my-3 p-3" rounded>
          <a href={`/postagem/${postagem._id}`}>
            <Card className="containerImg">
              <video className="containerImg" autoPlay loop muted>
                <source src={postagem.media} type="video/mp4"></source>
              </video>
            </Card>
          </a>
                    <a href={`/postagem/${postagem._id}`}>
          <Card.Body>
            <a href={`/postagem/${postagem._id}`}>
              <Card.Title as="div">
                <strong>{postagem.title}</strong>
              </Card.Title>
            </a>
                        <Card.Title as='div'>
            <Card.Text as="h4">Criado :</Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </>
    );
  };
                    </a>
  return (
    <div>
      {isImage ? <Condition1 /> : setImage(false)}
      {isImage ? <Condition2 /> : setImage(false)}
    </div>
  );
}
export default LastArticles;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'

function LastArticles({ postagem }) {

const DisplayImVi = () => {

    const isVideo = postagem.media.split('.').pop() === 'mp4'

    return( 
    <>
        <Card className='my-3 p-3' rounded>
                
            <a href={`/postagem/${postagem._id}`}>
        
                { !isVideo &&
                    <Card.Img className="containerImg" src={postagem.media} variant='top' /> 
                }

                {isVideo &&
                    <Card>
                        <video className="containerImg" autoPlay loop muted src={postagem.media}>
                        </video>
                    </Card>
                }

            </a>

            <Card.Body>

                <a href={`/postagem/${postagem._id}`}>

                    <Card.Title as='div'>
                        
                        <strong>
                            {postagem.title}
                        </strong>
                    
                    </Card.Title>

                </a>

                <Card.Text as='h4'>
                    Criado : 
                </Card.Text>

            </Card.Body>
    
        </Card>
    </>
    )
}

return (

    <div>
          {<DisplayImVi/>}
    </div>

)

}
export default LastArticles
```

To resolve this I had to remove one of the the conditions who was inside of the function `LastArticles`, removed the `useState` intead I made an variable calling the method `.split('.')` for search itens with the dot and the method `.pop()` for get the last item. Inside the `<a>` I short circuit evaluation to check and display both of the elements in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

This is duplicated useState, have only one time, correct the syntax, from this to,

```
const [isImage, setImage] = useState(true);
```

write like this, instead,

```
const [image1, setImage1] = useState(true);
const [image2, setImage2] = useState(true);
```

you can achieve it with `css` only,
using grid with two columns of screen display

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr;
}


<div class="wrapper">
  <div>{image1 ? <Condition1/> : setImage1(false)}</div>
  <div>{image2 ? <Condition2/> : setImage2(false)}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whitout add the code is like that.  https://imgur.com/8Zz9Qzr
Now adding the code its like that. https://imgur.com/xySl4tt